# Unhandled promise rejection beforeAll in e2e test with async await

Tags: promise, async-await, jasmine, e2e-testing, angularjs-e2e

I have been searching a solution for this warning for weeks, I looked a hundered github or stackoverflow topics but solutions gave me peace never or temporary. So I opened about this topic pls don't get mad at me I'm stuck.

I am writing e2e test with async await in AngularJs.

I canceled control flow with: `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false`

this is my login.Spec test file for testing login page:

```
var LoginPage = require('../pages/login.page.js');

describe('Testing Login Page', function (){
    const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var loginPage = new LoginPage();
    beforeAll(async () => {
        await loginPage.get().catch((e)=>{
          console.log(e);
       })

        await loginPage.login().catch((e)=>{
          console.log(e);
       })
    });

    it('there should be user name and user password area',async () => {

        expect(await $('[ng-model="user.name"]').isPresent()).toBe(true);
        expect(await $('[ng-model="user.password"]').isPresent()).toBe(true);
    });

    it('there should be login button',async  () => {
        expect(await $('[test-id="loginSubmit"]').isPresent()).toBe(true);
    }); 

 });
```

this is my login.page.js for get and login functions:

```
let LoginPage = function(){
    const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    this.get = async ()=>{
        await browser.get(`${browser.baseUrl}`);

        await browser.wait(
            EC.presenceOf(element(by.css('.container.login'))), 30000,
            'Waiting too long to open login page'
        )
    }
    this.login=async ()=>{

        await $('[ng-model="user.name"]').clear().sendKeys(browser.params.login.user);
        await $('[ng-model="user.password"]').clear().sendKeys(browser.params.login.password);

        const loginSubmit = await $('[test-id="loginSubmit"]');
        await loginSubmit.click();        
    } 
}
module.exports = LoginPage;
```

this is my export config part in protractor.config.js:

```
framework: 'jasmine',
specs: ['../test/e2e/specs/*Spec.js'],
SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true, 
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 900000 //for  timeout error: timed out after 30000 msec waiting for spec to complete
},
getPageTimeout: 900000,     //for Error: Timed out waiting for page to load after 10000ms
                            //for Error: Angular could not be found on the page: retries looking for angular exceeded
allScriptsTimeout: 900000,  //for Error: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds.
                            //for ScriptTimeoutError: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds


multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ["--window-size=1368,700" ]
    }     
}],

onPrepare: ()=>{
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({        
                baseDirectory: 'test/e2e/results/',
                screenshotsSubfolder: 'images',
                jsonsSubfolder: 'jsons', 
                takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
                preserveDirectory: false,
                docName: 'index.html' ,
                cssOverrideFile: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    }).getJasmine2Reporter());
},
```

this is version of test packages in package.json:

```
    "jasmine": "^3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.0.0",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
...
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "protractor-beautiful-reporter": "^1.1.1",
...
```

Finally here is my error. I run e2e and before everything gives me this error and then it makes selenium start:

> ..
>   [10:43:11] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.42.zip
>   (node:17016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EPERM: operation
>   not permitted, rename
>   'C:\ProjectPath\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver.exe'
>   -> 'C:\ProjectPath\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.42.exe'
>       at Object.fs.renameSync (fs.js:766:18)
>       at unzip (C:\ProjectPath\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\cmds\update.js:235:8)
>       at files_1.FileManager.downloadFile.then.downloaded (C:\ProjectPath\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\cmds\update.js:205:13)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) (node:17016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:17016) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
>   Blockquote

Okay I tried to put catch block after every test but it seemed not good and didn't get the solution.
I made ever function,on async and put before every statement await.
I tried to remove browser.wait() in beforeAll code block but it didn't work too so I take it back.

I mean my test run with success and sometimes I don't even get this warning at all. But I changed nothing then it keeps giving me this error.

How can I prevent the unhandled promise rejection?

Comment: if i understand correctly the error, its related to webdriver-manger update. It cannot rename the chromedriver.exe due possible read-write flag. Meaning this file its currently in use. Please verify that chrome drive is not running before updating it.

Comment: thanks for answer @Infern0 how can I verify that, how can I fix? is this cause of unhandled promise error too?

Comment: is your package.json script for example "test" or "pretest" contains webdriver manger update?

Comment: yes  @Infern0 "pree2e": "node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl",
"e2e": "protractor .config/protractor.config.js" should I remove that?

Comment: this script will update browser drivers before run, its not necessary to do it every time due limit from github and issues like yours. remove it, but keep in mind to check for new versions on demand. In two words it was trying to update chrome driver, but since its in use due "many" things it was failing your testing with unleaded promise.

Comment: "WebDriverJS (and thus, Protractor) APIs are entirely asynchronous. All functions return promises." So,  'Unhandled promise rejections' will be part of your error stack trace. Focus on the first part, try `webdriver-manager clean` before `webdriver-manager update`.